# How to restore a previously deleted group

Tags: ckan

I created a group, then deleted it, and now when I want to create it again I get the following error:

```
The form contains invalid entries:
Name: Group name already exists in database
```

Digging around I realized I can finally rase it from outside ckan. From a pgadmin3 console I have to delete related records in member_revision, member, group_role and finally group table

But doing so I break all the history in the audit tables, and god knows what else.

Is there some politer way to achieve it?

Comment: Instead of creating a new group, you could try to "undelete" the old one. Unfortunately there is not yet a clean way to do this, so you still have to fiddle with the database directly. But at least you don't loose the whole history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest (and probably dirtiest) way to do this, assuming your group name is my-group:

```
update group_revision set state='active' where name='my-group' and current=true;
update group set state='active' where name='my-group';
```

This should keep the audit intact.